# Will standalone scala program takes advantage of distributed/parallel processing? or does spark Scala require separate code?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

First of all sorry for asking the basic doubt over here, but still explanation for the below will be appreciable..

i am very new to scala and spark, so my doubt is if i write a standalone scala program, and execute it on spark(1 master 3 worker), will the scala program takes advantage of disturbed/parallel processing, or should i need to write a separate program to get an advantage of distributed processing??

For example, we have a scala code that process a particular formatted file to comma separated file, it takes a directory as input and parses all file and write an output to single file(each file will be usually 100-200MB). So here is the code.

```
import scala.io.Source
import java.io.File
import java.io.PrintWriter
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import java.util.Calendar

//import scala.io.Source
//import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
//import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
//import org.apache.spark.SparkConf


object Parser {

  def main(args:Array[String]) {

    //val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("fileParsing").setMaster("local[*]")
    //val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  var inp = new File(args(0))
  var ext: String = ""
  if(args.length == 1)
  { ext = "log" } else { ext = args(1) }

   var files: List[String] = List("")

   if (inp.exists && inp.isDirectory) {
        files = getListOfFiles(inp,ext)
        }
    else if(inp.exists ) {
         files = List(inp.toString)
    }
else
{
    println("Enter the correct Directory/File name");
    System.exit(0);
}

    if(files.length <=0 )
    {
    println(s"No file found with extention '.$ext'")
    }
    else{
            var out_file_name = "output_"+Calendar.getInstance().getTime.toString.replace(" ","-").replace(":","-")+".log"
            var data = getHeader(files(0))
            var writer=new PrintWriter(new File(out_file_name))
            var record_count = 0

            //var allrecords = data.mkString(",")+("\n")
            //writer.write(allrecords)
            for(eachFile <- files)
                {
                    record_count += parseFile(writer,data,eachFile)
                }
            writer.close()
            println(record_count +s" processed into $out_file_name")

    }
//all func are defined here.
}
```

Files from the specific dir are read using scala.io 
Source.fromFile(file).getLines

So my doubt is will the above code(standalone prg) can be executed on distributed spark system? will i get an advantage of parallel processing??

ok, how about using sc to read file, will it then uses distributed processing

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("fileParsing").setMaster("local[*]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
...
...
for(eachFile <- files)
                {
                    record_count += parseFile(sc,writer,data,eachFile)
                }

------------------------------------
def parseFile(......)
sc.textFile(file).getLines
```

So if i edit the top code to make use of sc then will it process on distributes spark system.

Answer (score 3):

No it won't. To make use of distributed computing using Spark, you need to use SparkContext.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the application you have provided using `spark-submit` you will **not** be using the Spark cluster at all.  You have to rewrite it to use the `SparkContext`.  Please read through the [Spark Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html).

Comment: Thanks you, So if i use SC for reading the file, then, will program make use of spark processing capabilities??

Comment: If you use SC in the way that the programming guide suggests, then yes, it will use Spark.

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely helpful to watch some introductory videos on Youtube for getting to know how Apache Spark works in general.

For example, these: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7k4yDKBYOcw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvDpBTV89AM&list=PLF6snu5Jy-v-WRAcCfWNHks7lcNO-zrTI&index=4

Is is very important to understand it for using Spark.

*"advantage of distributed processing"*

Using Spark can give you advantages of distributing processing on multiple server cluster. So if you are going to move your application later to the cluster, it makes sense to develop application using Spark model and corresponding API.

Well, you can run Spark application locally on your local machine but in this case you won't get all the advantages the Spark can provide.

Anyway, as it is said before, Spark is a special framework with its own libraries for developtment. So you have to rewrite your application using Spark context and Spark API, i.e. special objects like RDDs or Dataframes and corresponding methods.